# Faking website integration

Tags: html, user-interface, demo

I am working on a prototype for a project that is somewhat similar to the facebook's "like" button. Basically it's an embeddable piece of code that can integrated with any website.

I am looking for a way to fake this integration for a demo. Basically I want to show a familiar web page (like http://www.cnn.com) with my code already embedded. Since I obviously can't do the actual integration right now, I need some way of faking it.

The only thing I can think about is to use http://www.httrack.com/ to download the page I want, and then change it locally. The problem with this is that it is clear that the page is hosted locally and not on www.cnn.com.

Is there a better technique for doing this?

Comment: Do you want to fake the DOM-Model only?

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [Firefox browser](http://www.mozilla.com/lv/firefox/), you can use [Greasemoneky](http://www.greasespot.net/) and with JavaScripts, embedd your content inside that page. You can eaven add events, that will open some popup windows, etc. to show action of such a script.

That is easy approach, there are ton's of examples in their forum, and good documentation, how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own userscript (i.e. greasemonkey) to modify the page on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I think it's a bad idea to do this (not sure if stackoverflow allows to ask such questions), but what you can do is edit the hosts file (if you're on windows) and add a line

```
127.0.0.1 www.cnn.com
```

it means that when you visit the website cnn it will display the domain name in the browser but it will use your localhost server to display the content.